# Direct Sum and Linear Operators

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, direct-sum

I'm struggling with a question on linear operators and direct sums. If someone could possibly help me out here that would be great. The question is as follows:

> Let $V$ be a vector space.
>
> Let $U$ and $W$ be subspaces $V$, such that $ V=U⊕W $. Define $ T\colon V \to V $ by $T(v)=w$ where $v$ is written (uniquely) as $v=u+w$ with $u$ in $U$ and $w$ in $W$.
>
> Show that $T$ is a linear operator, $U=\ker T$, $W=\mathrm{im}\,T$, and $T^2 = T$.

I'm not sure how to approach this question. I know i should start with what we know which is the definition of a direct sum where $V=U⊕W$ needs to fulfil the 2 conditions - 1) $V=U+W$ and 2) $U∩W={0} $

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You mean $V = U \oplus W$?

Comment: Yes, I couldn't figure out how to format the special +. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you are struggling. With what part? What have you managed to do, and where are you stuck (and why)?

Comment: I'm not sure how to approach this question. I know i should start with what we know which is the definition of a direct sum where $V=U⊕W $ needs to fulfil the 2 conditions - 1)$V=U+W$ and 2) $U ∩ W = {0}$

Comment: Well, you are trying to prove a certain map is a linear transformation. Why not check to see whether $T(v_1+v_2) = T(v_1)+T(v_2)$, and $T(\alpha v) = \alpha T(v)$, for a start? Then you can try to figure out what this tells you about $v$s such that $T(v)=0$, and the rest.

Comment: Okay I proved that this map is a linear transformation. But I am still confused on where i would use the  $U=kerT$, $W=imT$, and $T^2=T$ in my solution

Comment: You don't need this to prove linearity. These are just additional properties of your linear operator.